# $f_{n} \in L^{p} \cap L^{q}$. Convergence in $L^{p}$ and boundedness in $L^{q}$ implies convergence in $L^{r}( p \leq r <q)$

Tags: functional-analysis

$$1 \leq p,q < \infty, \hspace{3mm} \mu(X) < \infty$$
Let $f_{n}$ be a sequence in $L^{p} \cap L^{q}$ and let $f \in L^{p}$. Assume that $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{p}$ and $\|f_{n}\|_{q} \leq C$.

Prove that $f \in L^{r}$ and that $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{r}$ for every $r$ between $p$ and $q$. $r \neq q$.

My attempt:

There exists a subsequence which converges almost everywhere to $f$ in $L^{p}$.
Thus applying Fatou's lemma to $f_{n_k}^{q}$, I get that

$$ \int \liminf |f_{n_k}|^{q} \leq \liminf \int |f_{n_k}|^q  \leq C^{q}$$
Thus, $f \in L^{q}$.

Consider the set $A= { |f| \leq 1 }$. This set is measurable. WLOG we assume that $p \leq r < q$. Then

$$ \int |f|^{r} = \int_{A} |f|^{r} + \int_{A^{c}} |f|^{r}$$
$$              \leq \int_{A} |f|^{p} + \int_{A^{c}} |f|^{q} < \infty$$

Thus $f \in L^{r}$.

I have difficulty in showing that $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{r}$. I was thinking of breaking the measure space into $B=|f_n-f| \geq 1$ and its compliment, but since $f_{n}$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^{q}$. I don't think it works. Can someone please help?

Comment: By Hölder's inequality, $\|f_n-f_m\|_{L^r} \le \|f_n-f_m\|_{L^p}^{1-\theta}\|f_n-f_m\|_{L^q}^\theta$ for an appropriate $\theta \in [0,1]$. The convergence in $L^p$ and the boundedness in $L^q$ thus allows you to conclude $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^r$.